# Watson IBM speech to text: no interim_result (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am trying to get `interim_results` with node.js

```
var params = {
audio: fs.createReadStream('./out.wav'),
content_type: 'audio/l16;rate=16000',
continuous: true,
interim_results: true,
word_confidence: true
};
```

I create my session with `speech_to_text.createSession`, then I try to start the `recognize` function :

```
function recognize(params,session_id,cookie_session) {
setInterval(function(){ observe_results(session_id,cookie_session) }, 1000);
speech_to_text.recognize(params, function(err, transcript) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log("OK")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(transcript, null, 2));
        fs.writeFile('./transcript.txt', JSON.stringify(transcript), function(err) {if(err){return console.log('err')}});
    }
});}
```

but I only receive the last transcription and not `interim_results`.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: 11/4**:
Starting from v1.0 the `watson-developer-cloud` npm module supports websockets.

See: [how to create a blob in node.js to be used in a websocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056373/how-to-create-a-blob-in-node-js-to-be-used-in-a-websocket)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:
You are calling `recognize` instead of `recognizeLive`.

See the example below:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud'),
  fs = require('fs');

var speechToText = watson.speech_to_text({
 password: '<password>',
 username: '<username>',
 version: 'v1'
});

var noop = function(){};

var observeResult = function(err, transcript) {
  if (err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  // print the transcript
  console.log(JSON.stringify(transcript, null, 2));
};

speechToText.createSession({}, function(err, session){
  if (err){
    console.log('error:', err);
    return;
  }

  var request = speechToText.recognizeLive({
    content_type: 'audio/l16;rate=44100',
    continuous: true,
    word_confidence: true,
    interim_results: true,
    session_id: session.session_id,
    cookie_session: session.cookie_session }, noop);

  // call observe result to get intermin results
  speechToText.observeResult({
    interim_results: true,
    session_id: session.session_id,
    cookie_session: session.cookie_session }, observeResult);

  // pipe the audio to the request
  // once the stream is consumed it will call request.end()
  fs.createReadStream('audio.wav').pipe(request);
});
```

Replace `username` and `password`, use this [audio](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/nodejs-wrapper/blob/master/test/resources/audio.wav?raw=true).

I wrote a [glist](https://gist.github.com/germanattanasio/359580d99ea22f47c6ba) for future reference. It also contains the output when using the audio above.