# how to create a blob in node.js to be used in a websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket, blob, ibm-watson

I'm trying to use IBM's websocket implementation of their speech-to-text service.  Currently I'm unable to figure out how to send a .wav file over the connection.  I know I need to transform it into a blob, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Right now I'm getting errors of:

`You must pass a Node Buffer object to WebSocketConnec`

-or-

`Could not read a WAV header from a stream of 0 bytes`

...depending on what I try to pass to the service.  It should be noted that I am correctly sending the start message and am making it to the state of listening.

Comment: Could you please add the piece of code here that results in the errors you mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the v1.0 (still in **beta**) the [watson-developer-cloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud) npm module has support for websockets.

```
npm install watson-developer-cloud@1.0.0-beta.2
```

Recognize a wav file:

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

var speech_to_text = watson.speech_to_text({
  username: 'INSERT YOUR USERNAME FOR THE SERVICE HERE',
  password: 'INSERT YOUR PASSWORD FOR THE SERVICE HERE',
  version: 'v1',
});


// create the stream
var recognizeStream = speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream({ content_type: 'audio/wav' });

// pipe in some audio
fs.createReadStream('audio-to-recognize.wav').pipe(recognizeStream);

// and pipe out the transcription
recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));


// listen for 'data' events for just the final text
// listen for 'results' events to get the raw JSON with interim results, timings, etc.

recognizeStream.setEncoding('utf8'); // to get strings instead of Buffers from `data` events

['data', 'results', 'error', 'connection-close'].forEach(function(eventName) {
  recognizeStream.on(eventName, console.log.bind(console, eventName + ' event: '));
});
```

See more examples [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples).